# Why does canvas's drawImage scale inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, scaling

I'm rendering an image to a canvas. After reading the drawImage [MDN API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), it looks like the following two lines of code should produce the same result:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.image.width, this.image.height, 0, 0, this.clip.width, this.clip.height);
ctx.drawImage(this.image,                                            0, 0, this.clip.width, this.clip.height);
```

But they DON'T! and I can't figure out why. The first one scales the image to fill up `this.clip`, which is what I expect. But the second doesn't seem to scale to mater what `this.clip` is, and the image seems to go outside of its own bounds.

Now, this is an image I generated in javascript, so is there any way I could have screwed up the image creation such that this would happen?

If it helps. This below is the code I use to make the image.

```
this.image = new Image(this.getSize()[0],this.getSize()[1]);
//this.getSize() = [32, 42, 40];
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var pixels = ctx.createImageData(this.image.width, this.image.height);
for (var x = 0; x < this.image.width; x++) {
     for (var y = 0; y < this.image.height; y++) {
         var i = (x + y*this.image.width)*4;
         var color = scalarToHue(this.sample(x,y,layer),0,10,50);
         pixels.data[i] = Math.round(color[0]*255);
         pixels.data[i + 1] = Math.round(color[1]*255);
         pixels.data[i + 2] = Math.round(color[2]*255);
         pixels.data[i + 3] = 255;
     }
}
ctx.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);
this.image.src = c.toDataURL("image.png");
```

Also, I'm using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are hard-coding your `image`'s width and height properties by setting it in the `Image(width, height)` constructor.

`ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy [, dwidth ,dheight])` will make `swidth` and `sheight` default to your image's [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and `naturalHeight`, not to their `width` and `height` ones.

So in your code, this means that the first line will use 32 and 42 as values for swidth and sheight, while the second line will use 300 and 150 if I read your code correctly.

Ps: re-reading your code, it seems that all you want is to set your canvas's width and height to these values before drawing on it, then you'll just need the `drawImage(x, y)` version.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it:  I never set the size of the canvas, so the canvas defaulted to 300x150. This was never a problem in my other images, because the other images were larger than 300x150, and I guess calling ctx.createImageData automatically makes the canvas large enough to fit the dimensions you enter.  In any case, calling `c.width = this.image.width;  c.height=this.image.height;` fixes the problem.